# docker-compose error what is this?

Tags: linux, docker, centos

I want to `docker-compose up` this file:

```
identidock:
build: .
ports:
 - "5000:5000"
environment:
ENV: DEV
volumes:
 - ./app:/app
```

but it has a error:

`ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'build' must be a mapping not a string.`

What should i do?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get an (useful) answer. Use the `{}` button on the question editor to properly format the content of the `docker-compose.yml` file posted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message I guess the content of the `docker-compose.yml` file is not properly formatted as YAML.

Make it look like this (keep the leading spaces on all lines) and it will work; or, at least, you will encounter a different type of error:

```
identidock:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  environment:
    ENV: DEV
  volumes:
    - ./app:/app
```